# How to achieve this alignment with Taburalize in Vim?

Tags: vim, tabular

So I have a code like this:

```
func "abc","def"
func "a little long",     {a: "string"}
func "hello", ["a", "b", "c"]
```

And I want this to align as:

```
func           "abc", "def"
func "a little long", {a: "string"}
func         "hello", ["a", "b", "c"]
```

I've been trying variations of `:Tabularize /",\zs/`, appending `r0`, `r1`, etc, but I don't have any idea of what I'm doing.

Any ideas?

If this can be done via some clean vimscript/macros, that would also be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func |          "abc", |"def"
func |"a little long", |{a: "string"}
func |        "hello", |["a", "b", "c"]
```

We want to select only the first `"foo",` of each line.

```
:Tab /^func \zs"[^"]*",/l1r1
```

Comment: Amazing! You've saved me so much time :)